# perl input from STDIN pipe only works with perl in front of script

Tags: perl, command-line, pipe

I am attempting to read from STDIN with a perl script.

Here is the script I am using for testing:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

foreach $line (<>) 
{
  print $line;
}
```

So from the command prompt, I type:

```
> cat somefile | testscript
>
```

It returns nothing with no error.

I then type the following:

```
> cat somefile | perl testscript
> *the contents of the file are printed line by line*
```

I really do not want the users to have to append perl in front of the script if I do not have to.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You can solve this by doing `while(<>)` and work on the variable `$_`. There is a lot of magic going on with `while(<>)` that does not occur if you do access `<>` in another context.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld Do you know what kind of magic? Both the above examples seem to work for me

Comment: Have you definitely got perl at /usr/bin/perl? Sometimes it's in a different location (e.g. /bin, /usr/local/bin) and the magic won't work. Otherwise, check your script is an executable (chmod 755 or similar)

Comment: I am running Scientific Linux if that helps.

Comment: `chmod 755 testscript; cat somefile | ./testscript`

Comment: while (<>) gives me the same results as my original post.

Comment: mpapec - That did it.  I guess once I install the script, it will be in a common area with the directory in PATH.  So the "./" will not be needed.  Thanks all.

Comment: @DanSchwitalla also consider `while <>`, and in this case drop `cat` for `testscript somefile`

Comment: Why not do `perl testcript < somefile`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you run two different versions of Perl. What is the output of "which perl"?